# Jquery adding class to wrong semantic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantics, addclass

I try to build image slider with markup `HTML` and `script` below:

#### HTML

```
<div id="button-previous">prev</div>  <div id="button-next">next</div>


<figure>

<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RiUUAdlHMSE/TehdEWtMyCI/AAAAAAAAASA/AXMQng9etR8/s1600/nemo.jpg">
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RiUUAdlHMSE/TehdEWtMyCI/AAAAAAAAASA/AXMQng9etR8/s1600/nemo.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mUIbhIqAyw4/Tehc-zbmK_I/AAAAAAAAAR8/MlPQb_D5P_A/s1600/walle.jpg">
<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mUIbhIqAyw4/Tehc-zbmK_I/AAAAAAAAAR8/MlPQb_D5P_A/s1600/walle.jpg"/>
</a>

<a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BRh1P_3XyDo/Tehc9UlYh0I/AAAAAAAAAR4/6TKLJs25ecg/s1600/up.jpg">
<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BRh1P_3XyDo/Tehc9UlYh0I/AAAAAAAAAR4/6TKLJs25ecg/s1600/up.jpg"/>
</a>

<a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-R_jrCzUDe-g/TehdHXDrK8I/AAAAAAAAASE/fW_-YGhHx20/s1600/toystory.jpg" >
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-R_jrCzUDe-g/TehdHXDrK8I/AAAAAAAAASE/fW_-YGhHx20/s1600/toystory.jpg"/>
</a>

<figcaption>no need class "active" or "oldActive" or on figcation sematic</figcaption>

</figure>
```

#### The script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('figure a').first().addClass('active');
    $('figure a').hide();
    $('figure a.active').show();

    $('#button-next').click(function () {

        $('figure a.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if ($('figure a.oldActive').is('figure a.oldActive:last-child')) {
            $('figure a').first().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('figure a.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
        $('figure a.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('figure a').fadeOut();
        $('figure a.active').fadeIn();


    });

    $('#button-previous').click(function () {
        $('figure a.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if ($('figure .oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
            $('figure a').last().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('figure a.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
        }
        $('figure a.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('figure a').fadeOut();
        $('figure a.active').fadeIn();
    });

});
```

### ISSUES WITH NEXT CLICK, (last-child)

1. No have any problerm with `#button-previous`.
2. But the script still
       send/add `class="active"` at `<figcaption>` after last-child of
       `figure a` when click `#button-next` at the `last-child of figure a`.
3. And slider will stop function rotate to fisrt-child back.

[[DEMO]](http://jqueryshah.blogspot.com/2013/10/modify-style-simple-slider.html)

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that inside the `figure` tag, `figcaption` is the last child, not the last `a` tag! So the second line of `$('#button-next').click` have to be changed from this:

```
if ($('figure a.oldActive').is('figure a.oldActive:last-child')) {
```

...to this:

```
if ($('figure a.oldActive').is('figure a.oldActive:nth-last-child(2)')) {
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjQGq/)